# Date time varchar conversion

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I've looked through other answers. For some reason they don't seem to fix my problem. This is the sql code:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'2012-00-00',120) AND CONVERT(datetime,'2013-00-00',120  )
ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC
```

I keep getting the following error message: 
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Why aren't you using `DateTime` type for your dates?

Comment: What "date" has a 0 month and 0 day?

Comment: The problem is that you use strings in the first place. There are several dozens of duplicates. Just *don't* use strings for dates, use parameterized queries. If you have to use strings in SSMS (never in code), use an *unambiguous* format - either the full ISO8601 or the unseparated date format

Comment: And there's no such thing as a date 0

Comment: @AnthonyHancock I want all dates in 2012

Comment: @JudahSchwartz and what's the first day of 2012?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you elaborate? I'm new to sql and don't know what you mean

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos op doesn't seem to be using strings for dates in his table, though

Comment: @JudahSchwartz you won't get them by passing an invalid string. Write `WHERE InvoiceDate between '20120101' and '20121231'` instead.

Comment: Between is inclusive, so it will keep the first date and last date. Just do BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'

Comment: @Lamak thank you so much. I feel like an idiot

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos should be `InvoiceDate >= '20120101' AND InvoiceDate < '20130101'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos op is converting to datetime, so it could include values like `20121231 10:01:01`, which will be filtered out with your condition

Comment: @Lamak if you convert to date, you don't need this. SQL Server is smart enough to compare dates with datetimes *and* use indexes. If you use date-typed parameters, or if you use *date variables` in the script, you can just write `between @from and @to`. If you type the string literal in the query itself, you'll have to write `cast(InvoiceDate as date) between '20120101' and '20121231' `. Just one more reason to avoid hardocding values in queries

Comment: The point is that you are **assuming** that op has only dates and not the time part too

Comment: @Lamak no, on the contrary. I'm not assuming. I'm saying that SQL Server can handle it. The cast was wrong though: it's `cast(InvoiceDate as date) between '20120101' and '20121231'`. If you check the execution plan you'll see that SQL Server turned this into a range query that covers all of `20121231` *and* uses indexes

Comment: well, for starters, that wasn't what you wrote in the first comment. And if you rather use `CAST` on the column instead of changing `BETWEEN` for `>= and <`, then I don't have anymore to say about it

Comment: @Lamak try it? You'll see that SQL Server can be smart about dates. It's cleaner to write the `BETWEEN` statement with the actual values you desire and the execution plan will be the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that, I just don't see the point. I disagree wholeheartedly that it's cleaner to use `CAST` on the column just to use `BETWEEN`, rather that just use `>= and <`. But, to each his own

Comment: @Lamak it's cleaner to write `< dateadd(d,1,@endddate)` you mean? Or doing a `someDate.AddDays(1)` in code? That I disagree with, wholeheartedly. The `>= AND <` looks clean only when you type the values directly, eg in SSMS

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
WHERE InvoiceDate >= '2012-01-01' AND InvoiceDate < '2013-01-01'
ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC
```

Comment: Or perhaps just `YEAR(InvoiceDate) = 2012` for simplicity +1.

Comment: But that would prevent the use of an index if there exists one on `InvoiceDate`

Answer (score 0):

You have the following: CONVERT(datetime,'2012-00-00',120). You can't make a date that doesn't have a day or month.

Answer (score 0):

Using a named parameter:

```
DECLARE @year INT;
SET @year = 2012;
SELECT *
FROM invoices
WHERE InvoiceDate >= DateFromParts(@year,1,1) AND InvoiceDate < DateFromParts(@year+1,1,1)
ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC;
```

If `DateFromParts` is not availanbe (pre-2012 MSSQL) the date can be created like this

```
WHERE InvoiceDate >= DateAdd(Year,@year-1900,0) AND InvoiceDate < DateAdd(Year,@year-1899,0)
```

Comment: It's a named parameter only if this is a paremeterized query. In any case, variable or parameter, you would onlly need a `BETWEEN @from and @to` if both parameters/variables are `date`